# how to pick a random string from an array every time the bot answers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to develop a simple discord bot which's made for chatting. I've created a string array that's supposed to store all answers the bot can give and then let the program give a random response based on that array. Now the bot does give a random answer but he only picks one random one from the array and only changes it when he's restarted. I was wondering if there's a way to make the bot pick a different answer every time he says something.
Here's the current code:

```
const stringarray = [
      'string1',
      'string2',
      'string3',
];

let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*stringarray.length);

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "string0") {
    msg.reply(stringarray[randomNumber]);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are setting `randomNumber` in the main code and not in the `.on('message')` callback! Therefore, the code is executed when you launch the server (and thus only once). You need to move it inside the callback for it to compute a new random value for each call:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "string0") {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*stringarray.length);
    msg.reply(stringarray[randomNumber]);
  }
})
```